# xhtml not showing session scoped values

Tags: java, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have a ManagedBean that is Session Scoped that injects another two Session Scoped Beans, they both have their proper getter and setters.

My class is as follows:

```
@ManagedBean(name="oneClass")
@SessionScoped
public class OneClassController implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{myOtherBean}")
    public AnotherClass another;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{requestBean}")
    public RequestClass request;

    public String foo() {
        another = getAnotherService(request);
        return "page?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    //getters and setters for AnotherClass and RequestClass
}
```

Now, the request class holds all the values for a web service request. Those values are filled within a form in a xhtml page.

When the user finishes filling up the request and fires the action from a button, it enters the `foo` method. The debug shows the request with the correct data, and when I call it, `another` gets filled up correctly.

Now, `page.xhtml` looks like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{requestBean.agentId}" />
<h:outputText value="#{myOtherBean.name}" />
<h:outputText value="#{myOtherBean.lastname}" />
```

When `page` is rendered, all the values from the `requestBean` are showed correctly, but all the `anotherBean` values show up empty. Even refreshing the page won't help.

If I trigger a button in `page.xhtml` to print out in the action method the values from `anotherBean`:

```
log.info("Another name: " + another.getName());
```

they print out fine.

I have in `web.xml` the saving method set for the server.

By the way, this is not the real naming convention I am using, but right now I'm in another computer without any IDEs nor JDK whatsoever, so I'm trying to replicate the code the best I can.

How can I show the correct values in `page`?

Comment: What's `another = getAnotherService(request);` doing in there if you're injecting it already with `@ManagedProperty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using,

```
<h:outputText value="#{oneClass.another.name}" />
<h:outputText value="#{oneClass.another.lastname}" />
```

To view all the variables in sessionScope you can do a:

```
<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope}" />
```

This will confirm if "myOtherBean" is in session scope or not.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I'll try it out tomorrow morning and see what happens :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But why is this happening? Isn't there a way where I could just use `another.name`?